# search column A for a string match in column B

Tags: postgresql, search

Using PostgreSQL, how can you search column A for a string match in column B?

Intermediate table (subquery) output:

```
string_a_id | string_a | string_b_id | string_b
-----------------------------------------------
1            'hello world'  11         null
2            'hello world'  13         null
3            'ipsum lorem'  21         'hello world'
```

Querying intermediate table above for match. **Expected output:**

```
string_a_id | string_a | string_b_id | string_b
-----------------------------------------------
1            'hello world'  21         'hello world'
2            'hello world'  21         'hello world'
```

I'm using

```
select * 
from (
    // subquery
) as subquery_results
where (trim(subquery_results.string_a) ilike trim(subquery_results.string_b))
```

but this returns 0 results.

Comment: Voted to close as unclear what you are asking because you never showed us the original data or the original query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Apologies, but I posted the intermediate table results I'm querying on further because a) the subquery producing the intermediate table is quite complicated and b) I didn't think it had much bearing on the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to compare each `string_a` with any `string_b` you should use self-join:

```
with dataset(string_a_id, string_a, string_b_id, string_b) as (
values
    (1, 'hello world', 11, null),
    (2, 'hello world', 13, null),
    (3, 'ipsum lorem', 21, 'hello world')
)

select q1.string_a_id, q1.string_a, q2.string_b_id, q2.string_b
from dataset q1
join dataset q2 on trim(q1.string_a) ilike trim(q2.string_b)

 string_a_id |  string_a   | string_b_id |  string_b   
-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------
           1 | hello world |          21 | hello world
           2 | hello world |          21 | hello world
(2 rows)
```

Replace `values` in the initial query with your actual query.

Comment: Okay, @TimBiegeleisen posted a similar answer - please see my comment to him under the original question. Since the subquery to produce the intermediate table I'm querying on further (the question above), which would be `dataset` in your answer, is quite complex, I didn't include it here because I didn't think it had bearing. So if this is the only way to do it, 1) how can I wrap `dataset` in something reusable (so I don't have to repeat the subquery logic) and 2) why doesn't `where (trim(subquery_results.string_a) ilike trim(subquery_results.string_b))` work?

Comment: Ah I just noticed your `with` statement

Comment: Instead of specifying the params in `dataset` (`dataset(string_a_id, string_a, string_b_id, string_b)`) - can I use a `*`?

Comment: No, but you can use `with dataset as ( select ...)` without params.

Comment: Great! Lastly, why doesn't `where (trim(subquery_results.string_a) ilike trim(subquery_results.string_b))` in my original question's attempt achieve this?

Comment: Because you compared columns in the same row only and  there were not matching pairs in a single row.